# How to correctly deal with API keys and storing data locally (C# wpf app)

Tags: c#, security, encryption, api-key

I'm currently facing a few issues which I need advice on.

I apologise in advance if the questions don't make much sense or if they have been answered before (I found somewhat relevant questions, but either didn't understand the answers or did not think they applied to my situation). Any guidance in this field or answers to the question would be extremely helpful.

Situation: We have a standalone app rolled out to customers, which uses AWS Userpools for user accounts.

***Issue number 1, storing the AWS (and other) API keys:***
I've read around and quickly realised the most secure location to store them is server side. 
We have an FTP server set up currently used for auto updates which I assume can also be used for retrieving the API keys.
Issue with this is that we still need to store the information to access the server somewhere securely.
What would be the best approach for storing and accessing API keys on server side?
Once API keys have been retrieved can we store them in memory to not have to access server again?

***Issue Number 2, feature flags:***
Due to different pay levels we have implemented feature flags, these flags are retrieved from a database when connecting to the app online.
However if they need to get on the app whilst offline they need to be stored locally in a way where they can not be modified.
Is it safe enough to encrypt the data and store it in a file locally and decrypt it on app startup?

***Issue Number 3, making sure the user is ok to use app if offline:***
As we want the user to not be able to log in after a set amount of days in offline mode without reconnecting I imagine I should be going down the route of using the AWS Userpool Tokens. How would one safely store these tokens to persist through app closure and is there any risk of storing them locally?

I imagine encrypting the server access information and feature flags in files is a way to go, however then we need an encryption key in order to decrypt these files. Where would one store that?
Note: I'm more concerned about the API keys rather than the feature flags.

Comment: I must admit that I cannot provide anything definitive, as I have struggled with similar issues in the past.  However, depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may be able to utilize a protected configuration.  You can read more about this by going to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files and scrolling down to the section about encrypting configurations.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll definitely look into this.

Regarding the API key problem I've spoken to a few people, and the only truely safe way to go about it would be to have my app make requests to a server and the server makes the appropriate requests to the required services.